# Zip in j2me using jazzlib

Tags: java-me, zip

I am using jazzlib package in j2me application to compress the xml file in zip format using ZipOutputStream and the send the compress stream to the server as a string . I am able to do unzip the in mobile using ZipInputStream.  But in server i am not able to unzip , i got 
EOF exception. when i copy the compressed stream from console and put into browser,  the empty space put special character like  [] in compressed stream. I didnt understand what happened. Plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send the compressed stream as a String? That's your problem(s) right there:

- compressed data is binary data (i.e. `byte[]`).
- `String` is designed to handle textual (Unicode) data and **not** arbitrary binary data
- converting arbitrary binary data to `String` is bound to lead to problems

So if you want to handle (send/receive/...) binary data, make sure you never use a `String`/`Reader`/`Writer` to handle the data anywhere in the process. Stay with `byte[]`/`InputStream`/`OutputStream`.